# Canvas only updates every other click

Tags: javascript, canvas, action

I am trying to draw an image into a canvas object via JavaScript, and change another image's source dynamically, when that image is clicked on. When an image I call the following JavaScript:

```
function clicked(i){    
switch(i){
    case(1): 
    source = document.getElementById("edit_pic").src = "images/1.png";  
    break;
    case(2) : 
    source = document.getElementById("edit_pic").src = "images/2.png";
    break;
    case(3) : 
    source = document.getElementById("edit_pic").src = "images/3.png";
    break;
    case(4) : 
    source = document.getElementById("edit_pic").src = "images/4.png";
    break;
    case(5) : 
    source = document.getElementById("edit_pic").src = "images/5.png";
    break;
    }
updateCanvas();
}


function updateCanvas(){
var c=document.getElementById("edit_canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
img = document.getElementById("edit_pic");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Whenever one of the 5 images is clicked on, the "edit_pic" image updates as expected, however the "edit_canvas" only draws the picture when you click the same image twice. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the image is still loading when you are executing the updateCanvas function at the end of the clicked function. You need to implement the onload callback on the image and execute your updateCanvas function from there. In other words...you need to go asynchronous on this:

```
function clicked(i){
   var img = document.getElementById('edit_pic');
   img.onload = function(){ updateCanvas(img); };
   img.src = 'images/'+ i +'.png';
} 

function updateCanvas(img){
   var c = document.getElementById("edit_canvas"),
       ctx = c.getContext("2d");

   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```